# Layout issue in tags filter field in new UI

Tags: bug, design, new-nav, user-interface

There is no way to edit the tags before [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2)

**(50.0.2661.37 (Official Build) beta (64-bit))**

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

**iceweasel 38.6.1**
[image: Firefox Screenshot]

For this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart%20dart-polymer%20flutter%20angular2%20polymer%20polymer-1.0?filter=all&sort=active&mode=any

On Linux Linux 4.4.0 KDE Plasma

Comment: Also occurs with Safari 9.1 on Mac OS X 10.11.4

Comment: Or see the tags that far left. This is still an issue for me.