# Display bug in the Edit Job Preferences modal

Tags: bug, tags, stack-overflow-jobs

[image: broken tags]

Firefox 45.0.1

It looks like the tag on the left side is being pushed out of sight.

Comment: Possibly related to this: [Layout issue in tags filter field in new UI](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319708). It looks like a somewhat similar issue.

Comment: This is when you have selected the field to make edits, correct? i.e. the cursor is flashing in that box. The text shifts to the left so you can see what you're typing in. If you want to edit things to the left, hit the left arrow key to scroll the box (just like an ordinary one-line textbox).

Comment: @AlexWarren No the text box isn't selected to make edits. However, you are correct when I do select it I am able to use the arrow keys to scroll left/right over the different tags. Thanks for clarifying how it works =).